Не с прилагательным - слитно или раздельно
Нарушение вида города скульптурой, не вписывающейся в ландшафт набережной.
Или:
Нарушение вида города скульптурой, невписывающейся в ландшафт набережной.
Вроде бы нет усиливающих, вводных слов и отрицания, а хочется написать раздельно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как всё-таки правильно?

Справочник Розенталя может подсказать, пункт 1 и 2  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80

Вы знаете, что такое причастие? Это особая  форма глагола, которая имеет окончания прилагательных.  Можно прочитать у Литневской https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p67_TOC_idp1659310080

У нас причастие с зависимым словом: не вписывающейся в ландшафт.
Нарушение вида города скульптурой, не вписывающейся в ландшафт набережной.

